# SQL Server Transaction backups - should overwrite file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup, transaction-log

Heyo,

This question is quite simple. I have a T-SQL backup script run by SQL Server Agent.

A differential backup is taken every hour, bar once per day, when a full is taken.
After either differential or full, a transaction log is backed up.
In addition, every 10 minutes, the transaction log solely is backed up again.

I save the transaction log with the date including the hour in the file name; in other words, output to the same filename 6 times an hour, then a new transaction log file is made.

**Should I be saving to the same file 6 times per hour?** Is SQL by default appending to the log or is it overwriting? Will restore operations be more complicated with multiple backups in one file?

For completeness, here is the log backup statement:

```
BACKUP LOG @db
    TO DISK = '\\somedrive\path\sqlservername\yymmdd-hh.trn'
WITH NAME='Log network backup.', DESCRIPTION='long backup description with time, DB and server name'
```

The server versions are SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012.

Comment: SQL Server can append to an existing file or overwrite it, depending on what is specified in the `BACKUP` statement.  The default is to append (`NOINIT`). To overwrite, you would specify `WITH INIT`.  Append or overwrite?  That's a matter of personal preference.  I prefer to use a uniqe filename for each backup operation, so I never append.

Comment: If the earlier transaction log backup has just Transaction A, will a later backup have transaction A and B, or just B? That's what I don't understand about appending with the transaction log.

Comment: Check out Shawn McGehee's book [SQL Server Backup and Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/sql-server-backup-and-restore).  There's a free pdf download.